# Find function's zeroes, poles, their orders and the residue at each pole.

Tags: complex-analysis

Good evening, I'm little bit unsure on how to start to work with this function. I'm familiar with simple examples, when in the numerator you have just z, and in denominator simple fractions.

However, I'm stuck on this question.

f(z) = $\frac{(e^z)}{z(z-3)^2}$

So, the zeroes are in the numerator,  but since we have $e^z$, then there is no zeroes, since it's entire?

Poles are z and $(z-3)^2$, thus poles z=0, 3 and order for first one is 1, and for the second is 2.

I'm confusing now what is the order for $e^z$ and how to find residue from each pole.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$e^z$ has no poles, as it's holomorphic on the whole of $\mathbb{C}.$

At $z=0$ we have a simple pole of order 1. If you find the taylor series about $z=0$, which is: 
$\frac{1}{z}(1+z+\frac{z}{2}+...)(z-3)^{-2}=\frac{1}{z}(1+z+\frac{z}{2}+...)(\frac{1}{9}+\frac{2z}{27}+....)$. You now see that the coefficient corresponding to $z^{-1}$ is $\frac{1}{9}$, so that is the residue of the pole there.

At $z=3$ we have a double pole, we now need to find the laurent expansiong at $z=3$:
$\frac{e^{(z-3)}e^3}{(z-3+3)(z-3)^2}$=$\frac{1}{(z-3)^2}(e^3+e^3(z-3)+\frac{1}{2}e^3(z-2)^2_....)(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{z-3}{9}+\frac{(z-3)^2}{27}+...)$.

Therefore the coefficient corresponding to $z^{-1}$ is $e^3.\frac{1}{3}-e^3.\frac{1}{9}=\frac{2}{9}e^3$, and that must be the residue at $z=3$

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit confusing about double poles, but will learn it.